# Return type array in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter, highcharts

Ihave and ajax requesting in codeigniter function, and I just echo the result array like this `echo json_encode($array)`. What I wanted to do is to catch the return value to the ajax as an array which I will use in the chart (Im using Highcharts) as a series. But nothing happens with this code:

```
    var data2 = [];
    url = base_url+"/codeigniter/index.php/AssistanceMonitoringModule/assistanceMonitoring/getSeries";

        $.ajax(
        {
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: "query="+query,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            //data2 = data;
        },
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("XHR:"+xhr.status+"Error:"+thrownError);
          }

        });
```

This is how call it in my HIghchart:

```
$('#columnChart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['May 01', 'May 02', 'May 03', 'May 04', 'May 05', 'May 06', 'May 07', 'May 08', 'May 09', 'May 10', 'May 11', 'May 12', 'May 13', 'May 14','May 15','May 16', 'May 17', 'May 18', 'May 19', 'May 20']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series: data2
        });
```

I used the data2 as the array as I said nothing happens. :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define new function to initialize and call `highcharts` plugin onSuccess ajax, 
try this way

```
  $.ajax(
    {
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: "query="+query,
    success: function(data){
        //alert(data);
        //data2 = data;
        callHighChart(data);
    },
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("XHR:"+xhr.status+"Error:"+thrownError);
      }

    });

function callHighChart(data){
         $('#columnChart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['May 01', 'May 02', 'May 03', 'May 04', 'May 05', 'May 06', 'May 07', 'May 08', 'May 09', 'May 10', 'May 11', 'May 12', 'May 13', 'May 14','May 15','May 16', 'May 17', 'May 18', 'May 19', 'May 20']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series: data // ajax response;
        });
}
```

Comment: this is because the data gets populated only after ajax successful call

Comment: Can I have a follow up question, what if i want to do multiple ajax request and call only the callHighChart() function when I already supplied the data needed by the chart such as the title, xAxis, yAxis, and series information? Is it possible, becaus the categories is actually not a constant value. 

I tried to declare global variable but not working though.

Comment: you should used pass multiple parameter in `callHighChart(data, category,....., n)` function, and use them into highChart plugin

Comment: If that's the case, I can't do multiple ajax for readying my data before I pass them callHighChart? Because my chart isn't responding when Im storing my data to a empty variable and call the function after the closing colon of the ajax.